# Problemas con consulta en django

Tags: python, django

En la base de datos poseo estos valores

```
INSERT INTO `principal_ingresos` (`id`, `instalacion_id`, `natural`, `juridico`, `fecha`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1066, 0, '2017-01-04'),
(2, 1, 754, 0, '2017-02-08'),
(3, 1, 1253, 0, '2017-03-09'),
(4, 2, 2504, 0, '2017-01-04'),
(5, 2, 1551, 0, '2017-02-02'),
(6, 2, 3078, 0, '2017-03-08'),
```

y deseo saber la suma por instalación de los campos jurídicos y naturales
para ello hago la siguiente consulta

```
ingjur =ingresos.objects.filter(pk=id_instalacion).values('natural').annotate(sum=Sum('natural'))
```

Uso esta url para general un perfil para cada instalacion donde debo mostrar el resultado:

```
url(r'^detalle_inst/(?P<id_instalacion>\d+)$','principal.views.detalle_inst'),
```

Pero me doy cuenta de que cuando muestra el resultado en vez de sumar todos los valores naturales de la misma instalación, por ejemplo con `id=1`, me recorre la tabla o sea:

La **instalación 1** como resultado natural me muestra el primer valor natural de la tabla o sea `1066` y no la **suma** de todos los valores naturales de esa instalación.

La **instalación 2** muestra el 2º valor de la tabla:`754` y no la suma de la instalación con id dos.

Debe ser problema en la consulta, pero no me doy cuenta donde...

[image: Como vemos en el resultado de TOTAL DE INGRESOS NATUALES muetsra como resultado en vez de el total el primer valor de la tabla, lo mismo pasa en el la otra instalacion que muestra el 2do valor]

**template.html**

```
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="app-widget-tile   app-widget-tile-info">

<div class="intval intval-lg">
    $ {{ ing.sum|floatformat:"2"|intcomma }}
</div>
<div class="line">
<div class="title wide text-center">Total Ingresos Naturales</div>
</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**view.py**

```
def detalle_jc(request, id_jovenclub ):
jc = jovenclub.objects.get(pk=id_jovenclub)
datos=ingresos.objects.all()
print jc.ingresos_set.all()
ing=0
ing = ingresos.objects.filter(pk=id_jovenclub).values('jovenclub_id').annotate(sum=Sum('natural'))

ingjur =ingresos.objects.values('jovenclub_id').annotate(sum=Sum('juridico'))
sum=0
for ingreso in jc.ingresos_set.all():
    sum=ingreso.get_importe()
sum=(round((sum/jc.plan_gral)*100,2))

return render_to_response( 'perfil_jc.html', { 'ingjur':ingjur[0], 'ing':ing[0] , 'jc': jc, 'porciento':sum, 'datos':datos}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo que logro analizar es lo siguiente:

en tu views.py la variable **"ing"** retorna un solo valor, ya que comparas el **"pk"** con **"id_jovenclub"**, siendo que deberías comparar **"instalacion_id"** con **"id_jovenclub"** y despues hacer la suma de **"natural"**

debería ser algo así:

```
ing = ingresos.objects.filter(instalacion_id=id_jovenclub).values('jovenclub_id').annotate(sum=Sum('natural'))
```

espero sea de ayuda

Comment: ya esta lo agrege y se lo pongo aca $ {{ ing.sum|floatformat:"2"|intcomma }} Total Ingresos Naturales

Comment: Hola @ceslat, bienvenido a StackOverflow en español. Este tipo de aclaraciones se deben solicitar a través de comentarios, las respuestas deben de responder a la pregunta del usuario y no solicitar aclaraciones.

Comment: @frikinside Gracias por la aclaración

Comment: @ceslat nada, sin problemas. No te olvides pasar por el [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) para cualquier cuestión que te pudiera surgir sobre el funcionamiento del sitio

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esta consulta

```
ingjur = ingresos.objects.filter(pk=id_instalacion).aggregate(sum=Sum('natural'))
```